# where could I download the latest build of chrome os

Tags: google-chrome-os

Because when I search it on google. I only see the gdgt website with a download link for the first chrome os that has been release. Do you know where I can download a modified version of chrome os?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[here](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/) is the 'distro' most people use.